# Console.log of function returning object

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a function which is returning an object which has an object as value. I need to console.log the result of the function, however what I get is this:

```
 testedDatalayer: {
    event: 'mkt_pageInformation',
    eventDetails: { page: [Object], pagePath: '/' }
  }
```

I need to display the value as normal instead of [Object]. I know I can stringify it, however I really want to keep it as an object rather then string and make it look like this:

```
 expectedDataLayer: {
    event: 'mkt_pageInformation',
    page: { type: 'xxx', category: 'xxxx' },
    pagePath: 'xxxxx'
  },
```

Is there any way of keeping that structure and console logging the function without the need of strinfigy?

EDIT: doing it on node.js and logging to cmd

Comment: stringify only when logging. `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))`

Comment: @AZ_ that way, the object is still printed as [Object]

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: Well I just did it and its still [Object], so maybe im blind

Comment: Or maybe just don't know how to use console.log?

Comment: sorry, there was another problem, it works now, thanks @AZ_ feel free to make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`

Comment: Im still getting the same thing. Im trying it on node.js and printing in cmd however. @Shb

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Node, you could try using util.inspect:

```
const inspect = require('util').inspect;
console.log(inspect(yourObject,{depth: Infinity}));
```

For more info you could check the nodejs docs for it at:

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Answer (score 0):

You can format it as an object structure using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) third parameter to pretty print Object.

```js
var objectToLog = {
    expectedDataLayer: {
        event: 'mkt_pageInformation',
        details: { page: { type: 'xxx', category: 'xxxx' } },
        pagePath: 'xxxxx'
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objectToLog,null,4));
```